# Recommended GUI designing modules for beginning python coder

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x

Do any of you guys know of a module for making a GUI that would be easier for someone like me, who learned python as his first programming language?
If it matters I don't plan on making anything really complex, just something that allows me to make a window with a menu bar and some buttons.

Answer (score 2):

See [GuiProgramming PythonInfo Wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming) for a list of various choices of such modules and also of design tools that allow you design forms visually and have the resulting code partially or fully generated.

In terms of modules, the main Gui Programming modules for Python are wxPython, Tkinter, pyGTK, pyQT4 and PySlide.

In terms of which module to start with I guess that depends on your criteria (which haven't yet been clearly specified), but Tkinter is shipped with Python by default, so you could always start with that.

References for Tkinter are avaliable from [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/)